# Confusion about software for x86, x86_64 and x64

Tags: linux, 64-bit, x86

do softwares meant for x86, install on x86_64 and x64. I am focusing on linux.
What problems can occur.
I have never been comfortable with the differences.
Could you explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

x86 refers to 32-bit software. x86_64 and x64 both refer to 64-bit software. Running 32-bit software on a 64-bit version of Linux is not the same as on Windows where 32-bit apps are thrown into a Program Files (x86) folder, [some modifications are needed](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/534) such as installing ia32 libraries.

Comment: i am on fedora and suse.

Comment: You'll still need ia32, here's an article tailored to fedora (scroll down to *Installing 32-bit support libraries under 64-bit Fedora 9 Sulphur* ): http://www.metztli-it.com/blog/index.php/2008/06/28/ibm-lotus-symphony-1-on-64-bit-fedora-9?blog=4 . It's for Fedora 9 but it's still relevant with the ia32 libs.

Comment: will the 32 bit linux version work on x64
http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Comment: I have no idea as I haven't tried it. Some applications do not work with ia32. Out of curiosity, why aren't you using the 64-bit build of java? http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=35678